# Removing rows including values with invalid format

Tags: python, format, rows

I am currently using Python and I got a dataframe including a column with PartNumbers. 
These part numbers have various patterns: e.g. 500-1222-33, 48L48 etc.

However, I want to remove rows having the following format: e.g. 06/06/3582.

Is there a way to remove the rows with these value-patterns from the dataframe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an example of some of the code you've tried?

Comment: I initially tried to define the pattern of the values I'd like to remove using the re.compile function as follows:

pattern = re.compile('\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}')

But I'm not sure how to proceed.